# How Many Blast Shards Are In Each Zone?

Tags: infamous

I'm trying to collect 100% of the blast shards from each zone before I move on to the next, hoping that it will make it easier to find all of these. So, how many shards can be found in each of the following zones?

- Neon
- Warren
- Historic

I'm also curious if the side missions which reward blast shards count towards the total count of 350?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are:

- 147 shards in Neon ( only 146 reachable till you get a later power )
- 135 shards in Warren
- 68 shards in Historic

There are a total of 350 of them scattered around the map, and this count does not include shards obtained in other ways (such as from missions, as you noted).